# If Pikachu escapes from the gravitational field of a planet by jumping, what is the radius of the planet?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

I am looking for a solution with the least amount of assumptions on the planet or the infamous [Pikachu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pikachu).

That being said, I tried to express the mechanical energy of the system:

$E_m = \dfrac{1}{2}m_{\text{pikachu}}v^2 - G\dfrac{M_{\text{planet}} m_{\text{pikachu}}}{R_{\text{planet}} + h_{\text{pikachu}}}$ where $G$ is the universal gravitation constant.

Now, I'm trying to get $R_{\text{planet}}$, so I know if Pikachu escaped from the gravitational field, then $E_m \geq 0$.

So, by using Newtonian laws, we can get:

$$
\begin{align*}
& v^2(R_{\text{planet}} + h_{\text{pikachu}}) = 2GM_{\text{planet}} \\
\text{i.e. } & (R_{\text{planet}} + h_{\text{pikachu}})^3\dfrac{d\theta^2}{dt} = 2GM_{\text{planet}}
\end{align*}
$$
where $\theta$ is the angular speed of Pikachu.

I wonder if I could use the third law of Kepler as $\dfrac{d\theta^2}{dt} = \dfrac{4\pi^2}{T^2}$ where $T$ is the rotation period of the planet (unsure about this, in fact.)

Plugging it inside the above equation yields to :

$$
\begin{equation*}
\dfrac{(R_{\text{planet}} + h_{\text{pikachu}})^3}{a^3} = 2
\end{equation*}
$$

where $a$ is the semi-major axis of the orbit.

That sounds kind of absurd to me, and I cannot continue because $a$ is unknown.

What I tried also:

- Using the first law of Kepler, which didn't help due to unknown $C$ constant.
- Using kinetic moment conservation, which eventually gave me the same expression as the first law of Kepler.

There is no more information, but we can safely suppose we are working in the solar system (I would be curious about a more general solution!).

**EDIT**: Right, I cannot use Kepler's third law.

An unexplored idea would be to figure out an interval of the planet's radius, that would be also interesting to see if that's feasible?

Comment: Well, you would have to know how fast Pikachu can jump. And Kepler's third law doesn't apply because the planet's surface is not orbiting its center.

Comment: @Javier If we assume Pikachu can jump at a speed of $v_0$, how can we carry on?

Comment: Moreover I'm afraid that either $M_{\text{planet}}$ or $h_{\text{pikachu}}$ would still be unknown, if we could get another equation or value, I think it'd be possible.

Comment: -1. Unclear. Please can you include in your question a statement of the problem which you are trying to solve. The link which you provide does not explain what your problem is, and your title does not provide any restrictions at all. Making the single assumption that the radius of the planet is say 10 meters immediately solves the problem.

Comment: @sammygerbil This is exactly the problem I'm trying to solve, indeed, 10 meters is a solution of the problem. I'm looking for solutions for this problem, in particular, solutions which make use of the least reasonable assumptions.

Comment: You have not defined the problem. There appear to be no constraints. If 10m is a reasonable value for the radius of the planet, this is the only reasonable assumption you need to make. You cannot have less than 1 assumption, because there are no known values in your problem - everything is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot exactly determine the radius of the planet, but we can put a lower bound on it. The minimal assumptions we would need to know are

- How fast Pikachu can jump ($v$).
- The mass of the hypothetical planet ($M$).

If Pikachu can jump this fast and escape the planet, then we know that $v$ must be greater than the planet's **escape velocity**.

In particular, we know that before Pikachu jumps, he (I had to google the gender of Ash's Pikachu) will be at a radius $R$ away from the planetary center. Thus, his potential energy will be

$$U_0=-\frac{GMm}{R},$$

where $m$ is Pikachu's mass. Once Pikachu jumps, his kinetic energy will be

$$K_0=\frac{1}{2}mv^2.$$

Now, if Pikachu is to escape the planet, then, at an infinite distance, his potential energy will be $U_f=0$ and his kinetic energy will satisfy $K_f\geq 0$. Thus, by conservation of energy, we must have $U_0+K_0\geq 0$. Thus, we have the constraint

$$\frac{GMm}{R}\leq\frac{1}{2}mv^2$$

Which tells us that the planet's radius must satisfy

$$R\geq\frac{2GM}{v^2}$$

Thus, we can't know the radius exactly, but we can put a lower bound on it.

If, however, you do a repeated set of experiments in which Pikachu jumps at different speeds, you can determine the critical velocity below which Pikachu can not escape and above which he can. This would be enough to approximately calculate the radius of the hypothetical planet.

I hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

Escape velocity is the minimum speed needed to break free from a gravitational body, and it's independent of Pikachu's mass:

$$ v_e = \sqrt{\frac{2GM}{R}}$$

You should be able to derive this expression from the energy equation. You'll notice that we still don't know the velocity, mass or radius. The density, $\rho = \frac{4M}{3\pi R^3}$, relates two of these values, and it is about $5500$ kg/m$^3$ on Earth which yields

$$ v_e = R \sqrt{\frac{3 \pi }{2} G \rho }$$

meaning that the velocity increases linearly with the radius of the (assumed constant-density) planet. The cheetah is the fastest land mammal on Earth, and it has a top speed of about 120km/h which would set an Earth-density planet to a radius of about 25km. Since Pikachu is fictional, you'll have to decide whether to make the planet (and Pikachu's maximum  velocity) larger or not.